# Умножение и деление с округлением вверх

Tags: c++, округление, переполнение

Как посчитать значение математического выражения?

`ceil[a*b:c]`

, где `*`, `:` - операции умножения и деления в множестве вещественных чисел, `ceil` - округление вверх.

Пример: `ceil[2*3:5] = ceil[6:5] = ceil[1.2] = 2`.

Ограничения в коде: `a, b, c` типа `unsigned long long`.

Примеры в коде:

```
assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, 3ull, 5ull) == 2ull);

const auto max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();
assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, max, 2ull) == max);
assert(mul_div_ceil(max, 2ull, 2ull) == max);
```

Проблемы: переполнение при наивном умножении (в смысле получения неправильного результата, а не с точки зрения языка), потеря точности при наивном "перевод в `double` -> деление -> умножение -> перевод в `unsigned long long`".

Для простого деления с округлением вверх (`ceil[a:b]`) это можно сделать так:

```
(a % b == 0) ? a / b : a / b + 1
```

Comment: *"операции умножения и деления в множестве вещественных чисел"*, а потом *"unsigned long long"* - вы уж определитесь...

Comment: @user7860670 я определился: в коде ull, а выражение в R

Comment: @user7860670 то есть код должен имитировать математическое выражение в R, хоть типы ull, потому что языки не поддерживают R

Comment: В общем случае не решаемо. Например, если `a` и `b` равны по 10^18, а `c` - 1. И что тогда? Определитесь, что следует получить в таком случае.

Comment: @Harry в таком случае любой ответ

Comment: @вася в таком случае решения нет, так как здесь арифметика над конечным полем.

Comment: @becouse так я и говорю - выдавать любой ответ. Можно и ошибку компиляции, исключение, UB

Comment: `((__uint128_t)a * b + c - 1) / c` не по стандарту конечно, и зависит от платформы и компилятора, но все же вариант.

Answer (score 6):

Первый вариант : один множитель можно уменьшать пополам и результат умножения удвоить. Всё реализуется рекурсией.

Второй вариант сделать циклом: дробь умножать на два, и когда надо добавлять к сумме. Тип `divtype` представляет целое число плюс числитель дробной части. Делитель подразумевается `с`.

```
// g++-9 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -Os mul_div_ceil.cpp -o mul_div_ceil
# include <cassert>
# include <limits>
# include <utility>
# include <iostream>

// div + rem / c
// rem < c
struct  divtype {
  unsigned  long  long  int div ;
  unsigned  long  long  int rem ;
} ;

// (x+y/c) * 2 => x*2 + y*2 / c + перенос
divtype mul2  ( divtype  a , unsigned  long  long  int c ) {
  if ( c - a . rem > a . rem )
    return  { a . div * 2 , a . rem * 2 } ;
  return  { a . div * 2 + 1 , a . rem - ( c - a . rem ) } ; }
  
/*
// (x+y/c) + b/c => x + (y+b) / c + перенос
divtype add ( divtype a , unsigned  long  long  int b ,
  unsigned  long  long  int c ) {
  if ( c - a . rem > b )
    return  { a . div , a . rem + b } ;
  return  { a . div + 1 , b - ( c - a . rem ) } ; }
  
// a*b/c == ([a/2]*b/c)*2 + (a%2 ? b/c : 0)
// a <= b <= c/2
divtype mul_div_ceil_recursion  ( unsigned  long  long  int a ,
  unsigned  long  long  int b ,
  unsigned  long  long  int c ) {
  if ( a == 1 )
    return  { 0 , b } ;
  divtype a2 = mul_div_ceil_recursion ( a / 2 , b , c ) ;
  a2 = mul2 ( a2 , c ) ;
  if ( a % 2 )
    a2 = add ( a2 , b , c ) ;
  return  a2  ; }
*/

// (x+y/c) + (z+v/c) => x+z + (y+v)/c + перенос
divtype sum ( divtype a , divtype b , unsigned  long  long  int c ) {
  if ( c - a . rem > b . rem )
    return  { a . div + b . div , a . rem + b . rem } ;
  return  { a . div + b . div + 1 , b . rem - ( c - a . rem ) } ; }
  
// 5*b/c == b/c + 2*(2*(b/c))
divtype mul_div_ceil_cycle  ( unsigned  long  long  int a ,
  unsigned  long  long  int b ,
  unsigned  long  long  int c ) {
  divtype db  = { 0 , b } ;
  divtype res = { 0 , 0 } ;
  while ( a ) {
    if  ( a % 2 )
      res = sum ( res , db , c ) ;
    db  = mul2 ( db , c ) ;
    a >>= 1 ; }
  return  res ; }
  
unsigned  long  long  int mul_div_ceil (
  unsigned  long  long  int a ,
  unsigned  long  long  int b ,
  unsigned  long  long  int c ) {
  // a == ac * c + ar
  unsigned  long  long  int ac = a / c ;
  unsigned  long  long  int ar  = a % c ;
  // b == bc * c + br
  unsigned  long  long  int bc = b / c ;
  unsigned  long  long  int br  = b % c ;
  // a * b / c ==
  //   (ac * c + ar) * (bc * c + br) / c == 
  //   ac * bc * c + ac * br + ar * bc + ar * br / c
  unsigned  long  long  int result  = ac * bc * c + ac * br + ar * bc ;
  if ( ar && br ) {
    // ceil ( ar * br / c ) , ar < c , br < c
    // Оптимизация если числитель большой
    // ar * br / c == br - ( c - ar ) * br / c
    bool  flagceil  = true  ;
    if ( c - ar < ar ) {
      ar = c - ar ;
      result  +=  br  ;
      flagceil  = false ; }
    // ar * br / c == ar - ar * ( c - br ) / c
    if ( c - br < br ) {
      br = c - br ;
      if ( flagceil ) {
        result  +=  ar  ;
        flagceil  = false ; }
      else  {
        result  -=  ar  ;
        flagceil  = true  ; } }
    if ( br < ar )
      std ::  swap  ( ar , br ) ;
    //divtype dr  = mul_div_ceil_recursion  ( ar  , br  , c ) ;
    divtype d = mul_div_ceil_cycle  ( ar  , br  , c ) ;
    //assert ( d . div == dr  . div ) ;
    //assert ( d . rem == dr  . rem ) ;
    if ( flagceil ) {
      if ( d . rem )
        ++  d . div  ;
      result  +=  d . div ; }
    else
      result  -=  d . div ; }
  std :: cout << a << " * " << b << " / " << c << " = " << result << std :: endl ;
  return  result  ; }
  
int main() {
  assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, 3ull, 5ull) == 2ull);
  const auto max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();
  assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, max, 2ull) == max);
  assert(mul_div_ceil(max, 2ull, 2ull) == max);
  assert(mul_div_ceil(3ull, max-3, max) == 3);
  assert(mul_div_ceil(max-3, 3ull, max) == 3);
  assert(mul_div_ceil(3ull, max, max-3) == 4);
  assert(mul_div_ceil(max / 3 * 2 , max / 3 * 2, max / 3 * 2) == (max / 3 * 2)); }
```

Результат:

```
> ./mul_div_ceil
2 * 3 / 5 = 2
2 * 18446744073709551615 / 2 = 18446744073709551615
18446744073709551615 * 2 / 2 = 18446744073709551615
3 * 18446744073709551612 / 18446744073709551615 = 3
18446744073709551612 * 3 / 18446744073709551615 = 3
3 * 18446744073709551615 / 18446744073709551612 = 4
12297829382473034410 * 12297829382473034410 / 12297829382473034410 = 12297829382473034410
```

Comment: Интересно, сколько ей нужно времени, чтоб посчитать mul_div_ceil(max-1, max-1, max)

Comment: Дописал рекурсию, вот быстрый ответ: скорость **O(1)**. @nikiquark

Comment: Можете подробнее объяснить, как работает рекурсивная функция, что такое `mul2` и `add` и почему они так выглядят? Пока что это единственное решение, которое работает (по крайней мере я не нашёл контрпримеров).

Comment: Всё в комментариях проги. Обычная математика. Рекурсия просто складывает дроби. @вася

Comment: @AlexGlebe а чего вы картинку удаляете?

Comment: Я алгоритм переписал, картинка уже не в тему. @вася

Comment: Малость добавил оптимизацию на большие числители, чтобы было приятно.  @вася

Comment: Исправил рекурсию на цикл, для ускорения. @вася

Answer (score 1):

Вот частичное решение для случаев, когда a,b - большие, c - маленькое (не превышает корня из UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_MAX).

Для начала - немного математики:

a = a1 * c + a2, где a1 = a / c (целочисленное деление), a2 = a % c
b = b1 * c + b2, где b1 = b / c (целочисленное деление), b2 = a % c

Распишем и упростим выражение ab / c:

ab / c = (a1*c + a2) * (b1*c + b2) / c = (a1*b1*c*c + a1*b2*c + a2*b1*c + a2*b2) / c = a1*b1*c + a1*b2 + a2*b1 + a2*b2/c.

Первые три слагаемых - целые числа. Если их реально посчитать без переполнения, то задача решаема. В противном случае задача не решаема, и ничего вы с ней не сделаете.

Последнее слагаемое гарантированно считается без переполнения, потому что и a2, и b2 меньше, чем c, и поэтому a2*b2 < UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG_MAX.

Теперь код:

```
function getResult(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c)
{
    unsigned long long a1 = a / c;
    unsigned long long a2 = a % c;
    unsigned long long b1 = b / c;
    unsigned long long b2 = b % c;

    return a1*b1*c + a1*b2 + a2*b1 + ceil(a2*b2/c);
}
```

Comment: `assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, 3ull, 5ull) == 2ull);` проверяли? https://godbolt.org/z/hco4eg

Answer (score 1):

При умножении двух 64-битных чисел в общем случае результат должен уметь хранить 128 бит.

Если тип данных `uint128` недоступен, то его можно эмулировать, написав дополнительный код.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits>

// хранит 128-битное число вида: high_part * 2^64 + low_part
struct double_ull
{
    unsigned long long high_part;
    unsigned long long low_part;

    // конструирование из 64-битного unsigned long long
    double_ull(unsigned long long num)
    {
        high_part = 0;
        low_part = num;
    }

    // конструирование 128-битного числа из старшей и младшей 64-битных частей
    double_ull(unsigned long long high, unsigned long long low)
    {
        high_part = high;
        low_part = low;
    }

    // оператор сдвига числа влево
    double_ull operator << (unsigned short int count_bits) const
    {
        return double_ull
        {
            (high_part << count_bits) | (low_part >> (64 - count_bits)),
            low_part << count_bits
        };
    }

    // оператор сложения с unsigned long long
    double_ull operator + (unsigned long long right) const
    {
        return (*this + double_ull{right});
    }

    // оператор сложения с другим double_ull
    double_ull operator + (double_ull right) const
    {
        unsigned long long h_part = high_part + right.high_part;
        unsigned long long l_part = low_part + right.low_part;

        // перенос единички в high_part при переполнении в low_part
        if ((l_part < low_part) || (l_part < right.low_part))
        {
            h_part++;
        }

        return double_ull { h_part, l_part };
    }

    // оператор умножения
    double_ull operator * (unsigned long long right) const
    {
        // разбиваем старшую и младшую части числа на куски в виде a1 * 2^96 + a2 * 2^64 + a3 * 2^32 + a4
        unsigned long long a1 = high_part >> 32;
        unsigned long long a2 = high_part & 0xFFFFFFFFull;
        unsigned long long a3 = low_part >> 32;
        unsigned long long a4 = low_part & 0xFFFFFFFFull;

        // разбиваем right на куски в виде r1 * 2^32 + r2
        unsigned long long r1 = right >> 32;
        unsigned long long r2 = right & 0xFFFFFFFFull;

        // умножение a * r принимает вид:
        //   (a1 * 2^96 + a2 * 2^64 + a3 * 2^32 + a4) * (r1 * 2^32 + r2) =
        //   = a1*r1 * 2^128 + (a1*r2 + a2*r1) * 2^96 + (a2*r2 + a3*r1) * 2^64 + (a3*r2 + a4*r1) * 2^32 + a4*r2
        // самый старший кусок (a1*r1 * 2^128) отбросим - это переполнение

        // перемножаем куски чисел, конвертируем произведения в double_ull
        auto a1r2 = double_ull { a1 * r2 } << 96;
        auto a2r1 = double_ull { a2 * r1 } << 96;
        auto a2r2 = double_ull { a2 * r2 } << 64;
        auto a3r1 = double_ull { a3 * r1 } << 64;
        auto a3r2 = double_ull { a3 * r2 } << 32;
        auto a4r1 = double_ull { a4 * r1 } << 32;
        auto a4r2 = double_ull { a4 * r2 };

        return a1r2 + a2r1 + a2r2 + a3r1 + a3r2 + a4r1 + a4r2;
    }

    // оператор целочисленного деления
    double_ull operator / (unsigned long long right) const
    {
        // деление принимает вид: (m1 * 2^64 + m2) / right = m1 * 2^64 / c + m2 / right;

        // выполняем деление по кускам, накапливая остаток
        double_ull result { low_part / right };
        double_ull rem { low_part % right };

        // каждая единица, суммирующаяся в "high_part": 2^64 = (2^64 - 1) + 1 = max + 1
        // деление high_part выглядит как-то так:
        //   high_part * 2^64 / right = high_part * ( max + 1 ) / right = high_part * max / right + high_part / right
        if (high_part > 0)
        {
            constexpr auto max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();

            unsigned long long d1 = max / right;
            unsigned long long r1 = max % right;

            // первое слагаемое правой части
            result = result + (double_ull{high_part} *d1);
            rem = rem + (double_ull{high_part} * r1);

            // второе слагаемое правой части
            result = result + (high_part / right);
            rem = rem + (high_part % right);

            // ещё раз поделим остаток (в нём могло накопиться число большее, чем "right")
            result = result + (rem / right);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // умножение двух unsigned long long
    static double_ull mul(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b)
    {
        return double_ull{a} * b;
    }

    // деление с округлением вверх
    unsigned long long div_ceil(unsigned long long c)
    {
        return ((*this + (c - 1)) / c).low_part;
    }
};

unsigned long long mul_div_ceil(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c)
{
    return double_ull::mul(a, b).div_ceil(c);
}

int main()
{
    assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, 3ull, 5ull) == 2ull);
    
    constexpr auto max = std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();
    assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, max, 2ull) == max);
    assert(mul_div_ceil(max, 2ull, 2ull) == max);

    assert(mul_div_ceil(max / 2, max / 2, max) == (max / 4 + 1));
    assert(mul_div_ceil(max, max, max) == max);

    assert(mul_div_ceil(max / 3 * 2, max / 3 * 2, max / 3 * 2) == (max / 3 * 2));

    return 0;
}
```

Спасибо `AlexGlebe` за указание на ошибку.
Код исправлен.

Comment: `assert(mul_div_ceil(max / 3 * 2 , max / 3 * 2, max / 3 * 2) == (max / 3 * 2));` - падает. Деление перепишите, всё не так просто.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, благодарю. Вы поймали проблему переполнения в операторе `rem += high_part * r1;`. Её-то я и не учёл... Днём попробую улучшить.

Answer (score 0):

Для простого деления все делается проще -

```
(a+b-1)/b
```

Вероятность переполнения при умножении можно *попробовать* уменьшить, находя НОД и сокращая на него - для `a` и `c` и для `b` и `c`.

Как избежать этих неприятностей вообще без использования чего-то подлиннее - не знаю, мне кажется, что это невозможно.

Comment: Ваш вариант для простого деления выдаёт неправильный результат. https://godbolt.org/z/oMJg6y

Answer (score 0):

Надо сначала поделить `a` или `b` на `c`, а после умножить на оставшийся множитель. Тогда переполнения не будет.

Comment: Так как в итоге правильный результат получить? Вот так ноль получается `(2ull / 5ull) * 3ull`

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, не самое красивое решение, но рабочее. Решил просто символьную арифметику использовать

```
#include <vector>
typedef unsigned long long ull;
ull mul_div_ceil(ull a, ull b, ull c) {
    //Преобразование в массив
    std::vector<int>  num_a,num_b;
    while (a) {
        num_a.push_back(a % 10);
        a /= 10;
    }
    while (b) {
        num_b.push_back(b % 10);
        b /= 10;
    }
    //Умножение
    std::vector<int> c_num(num_a.size() + num_b.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_a.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0, carry = 0; j < (int)num_b.size() || carry; ++j) {
            long long cur = c_num[i + j] + num_a[i] * 1ll * (j < (int)num_b.size() ? num_b[j] : 0) + carry;
            c_num[i + j] = int(cur % 10);
            carry = int(cur / 10);
        }
    while (c_num.size() > 1 && c_num.back() == 0)
        c_num.pop_back();
    //Деление
    ull carry = 0;
    for (int i = (int)c_num.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        ull cur = c_num[i] + carry * 1ll * 10;
        c_num[i] = ull(cur / c);
        carry = ull(cur % c);
    }
    while (c_num.size() > 1 && c_num.back() == 0)
        c_num.pop_back();
    //Обратное преобразование
    ull answer = 0;
    for (int i = (int)c_num.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        answer = answer * 10 + c_num[i];

    return carry ? answer + 1 : answer;
}
```

Comment: проверьте на `assert(mul_div_ceil(2ull, max, 2ull) == max);`

Comment: не проходит `assert(mul_div_ceil(5ull, max, 5ull) == max);` https://godbolt.org/z/rELW84

Comment: @AlexGlebe что интересно, для двоек проходит, код не проверял пока :)

Comment: @вася, согласен, есть переполнение. Если я код доделаю, то мне этот редактировать или новый залить?

Comment: @вася, чуть изменил умножение, теперь ваш случай пройдёт.

Comment: `assert(mul_div_ceil(max, max, max) == max);` https://godbolt.org/z/_9sNJz

Answer (score -2):

```
auto mul_div_ceil(auto a, auto b, auto c) {
   return ceil(a*(b/c));
}
```